# google script time format

Tags: forms, google-apps-script, google-sheets

Hi I have a set of google sheets and forms that is an automated vacation request and approval app. I was trying to use a copy of that to create a "time card correction" app. I changed the forms, sheets, and scripts so that it reflected only one date and then one of the questions was for the "new time". When the form gets submitted to a manager and he/she sees it in an email and they have a choice to approve or deny the request, the "new time" isn't formatted as a time but still as a date. I can't find where in the script I can change the date format to time. Can somebody please help. I can share the necessary google files if somebody can help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I like to use moment JS in my apps script. But a fast way to get the time is to use the [Utilities](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#formatDate(Date,String,String)) class. This will return a full time stamp.

```
 var formattedDate = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT", "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'");
 Logger.log(formattedDate);
```

If you just want the time

```
 var formattedDate = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT", "HH:mm:ss");
 Logger.log(formattedDate);
```